# hide text between <label>abc</label> - remove ' abc '

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have a label tag and i want to remove text between  `<label> </label>`

**my string (html code) is**

```
<label style="cursor: pointer; " for="31">
<img src="/joomla_1.7/images/stories/virtuemart/product/resized/black4_90x90.png" alt="the"/>
<span class="vm-img-desc" style="display: none; ">the</span>
$12.93
</label>
```

i want to remove `$12.93` and i just want to image and the span in to `<label> </label>` tag

i am using `php` and `jQuery`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i just want remove `$12.93` from given html code by `jquery` or `php`

Comment: That doesn't tell me *what you've tried*.

Comment: @joy understand that `what i am tried ?`

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you?  Stack overflow is not a 'write my code for me' service.  You have to show some effort, and so far, you've shown none.  And no, Joy just gave you code..  you still haven't shown any attempts at achieving your desired end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case Just to remove the `$12.95` You can do

```
$('label').contents().last().remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/gFgF3/

Read more on [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

As it's not inside any tag it's a `textNode` `.contents()` returns all child elements including textnodes and in this case `$12.95 textNode` is the last child of label, So it will just remove that text( Price in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
empty()
```

But you should id your span for that or use a css selector :)
http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 0):

give your label some class or id and do i like this

```
$('#labelid').text('');
OR
$('.labelclass').text('');
```